# Using plural form for Russian localization

Tags: django, internationalization

I try to use the plural form in Russian language, but Russian has two forms of word for plural words (for example: "1 курс" = 1 course, "2 курс**а**" = 2 courses, but "5 курс**ов**" = 5 courses).

Django supports this peculiarity and specifies plural form using this algorithm (django.po headers):

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%"
"10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2;\n"
```

Description of plural form looks like this (django.po):

```
msgid "%(курс) курс"
msgid_plural "%(курс) курса"
msgstr[0] "%(курс) курс"
msgstr[1] "%(курс) курса"
msgstr[2] "%(курс) курсов"
```

How do I use this in templates? Something like this `{% sometag word="курс" counter=courses|lenht %}`? is there default tag, or do I need to implement this tag by myself?

Comment: @Tomasz Wysocki May you post an example?

Comment: "Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%" "10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2;\n" I hope n is the last digit, not the number itself?
Otherwise it is not correct for n = 21, 31, 41 etc
22-24, 32-34, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `blocktrans` as hinted by Thomasz. From the [blocktrans documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/#specifying-translation-strings-in-template-code):

> This tag also provides for pluralization. To use it:
>
> Designate and bind a counter value with the name count. This value
>   will be the one used to select the right plural form. Specify both the
>   singular and plural forms separating them with the {% plural %} tag
>   within the {% blocktrans %} and {% endblocktrans %} tags.
>
> An example:

```
{% blocktrans count counter=list|length %} There is only one {{ name
}} object. {% plural %} There are {{ counter }} {{ name }} objects. {%
endblocktrans %}
```

> A more complex example:

```
 {% blocktrans with amount=article.price count years=i.length %} That
 will cost $ {{ amount }} per year. {% plural %} That will cost $ {{
 amount }} per {{ years }} years. {% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've read the docs before. But it's not working in my case and I realy don't know where I'm wrong. I try using: `{% blocktrans with name="курс" count counter=own_corses|length %}{{ name }}{% plural %}{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}` in djnago.po: `msgid "%(name)s курс"
msgid_plural "%(name)s курсов"
msgstr[0] "%(name)s курс"
msgstr[1] "%(name)s курса"
msgstr[2] "%(name)s курсов"` result: "13 курс" — it's wrong.

Comment: You need only `{% blocktrans count counter=own_corses|length %}{{ name }}{% plural %}{{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}`